# how to show blank before item selected on dropdown box

Tags: php, html, mysql

My box is populating from my database but I would like to show the drop down box blank until it is clicked to select. Not quite sure how to do that. Thanks in advance

```
<select type="text" name='id' id="inputItem" placeholder="Item #1" class="form-control">
<?php

require ('dbconnect.php');
$result = $con->query("select id, item from items");

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

unset($id, $name);
$id = $row['id'];
$name = $row['item']; 
echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';

}

echo "</select>";
mysqli_close($con);
?> 

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `<option>Choose One...</option>` immediately after your first line.

Answer (score 0):

you could add blank option before `while` loop, as:

```
...
echo '<option value="">Select</option>';
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

unset($id, $name);
$id = $row['id'];
$name = $row['item']; 
echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';

}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select type="text" name='id' id="inputItem" placeholder="Item #1" class="form-control">
<option value=''>Select First</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before your while loop:

```
echo '<option value="">--- Select ---</option>';
```